# Nested cross-validation really necessary?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem with my cross-validation procedure. Currently I'm just looping (iterating) over my paramaters (e.g. C and gamma for RBF SVM) and doing an inner Leave-one-out cross-validation.

Of course this can introduce bias. So it would be better to do a nested cross-validation, for example an outer leave-one-out cross-validation and an inner 10-fold cross-validation.

The problems are that I only have 37 data points, a nested cross-validation increases the runtime by a lot and I also want to print for example for k nearest neighbours k against the accuracy or the number of hidden layers agains the accuracy (for neural network) which is not possible in nested cross-validation.

Is there really a big bias without using nested cross-validation or can I go with my single CV approach? Are there some papers which claim that a single cross-validation is ok?

Comment: How can it possibly be slow with just 37 data points?

Comment: Because I have around 200'000 features... And I'm using neural nets which are very slow. Anyway I think that I can get the best parameters by using a majority vote (or average). But how can I plot number of hidden layers or number of nearest neighbours against accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the statistical point of view, whatever you do with **37 data points** will not be statisticaly sound. Even the most precise analysis will not be generalizable to anything beyond this dataset. Instead of analyzing and spending time on the tests, you should do everything you can to get more data.

If you have bigger dataset, then "single CV" will nearly always overestimate your results. Size of this bias is hard to determine, in fact as far as I know it can be shown that it is actually unbounded. Refer to the section 7.10.2 in *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hasti and Tibshirani.

Comment: So with 37 data points it does not matter if I do nested CV or just single CV?

Comment: with 37 points nothing is significant, you can even toss a coin :-)

Comment: I would think it is still useful to estimate the performance using a nested leave-one-out scheme?

Answer (score 3):

In nested cross validation, you find the best parameters for different subsets of the data (the outer folds). I can't say for sure how much it will hurt if you don't use nested CV, but according to [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103828/use-of-nested-cross-validation) (which links to [this paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf)), it can be noticeable.

Now, you say you want to plot number of hidden layers against accuracy. This isn't how nested CV works: nested CV tells you, among others, how much you can rely on a parameter choice to generalize well for unseen data. For example, let's say you do a grid search for `1, 2, 5, 10` hidden layers in the inner CV. If the results of the outer CV for hidden layers differs a lot between folds, then this means that you cannot be sure what number of hidden layers will generalize well. If they all end up choosing the same number of hidden layers, that's great.

I suggest you also read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_diabetes.html#example-exercises-plot-cv-diabetes-py) (in python, but it's another example for what I want to point out) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection), which is a great explanation of what nested CV does. Of particular interest is this paragraph:

> The outer cross validation estimates the performance of this model fitting approach. For that you use the usual assumptions

So basically, nested CV tells you how good your hyperparameter search is. You can't plot accuracy versus some hyperparameter at this step. You can see if the same hyperparameter (or close enough) is chosen for different parts (folds) of the data.

If you have a lot of data, consider reducing the number of features or running things in parallel (you mention neural nets: they become much less slow if run on the GPU).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I know that I cannot plot the number of hidden layers against the accuracy with nested CV. But if I want (or need) to do that how should I do it? Just using single CV? But this would introduce bias...

Comment: @machinery - nested CV can tell how good your parameter search is. Decide on your parameter search method and run it through nested CV. If it's not good enough, tweak something. If it's good enough, then run your parameter search on your entire data, and you can now plot what you're interested in.

Comment: Do you mean running my parameter search on my entire data with only single CV? Will this not introduce bias?

Comment: @machinery read the stats.stackexchange.com link I posted and the accepted answer there. The outer CV will tell you what that bias is. Ideally, you want the outer CV results to be very close together. If they are very close, then there will be no bias because whatever you choose with the single CV will be equivalent (or close to) the other things you could have chosen.